# I am trying this below code to find the 'Images' button and click on that using python in Pycharm. But its showing some errors

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, findelement

```
C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py:11: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\driver\chromedriver.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Images")
  File "C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\PWTTS\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Images"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x007E1ED3+2236115]
    Ordinal0 [0x007792F1+1807089]
    Ordinal0 [0x006866FD+812797]
    Ordinal0 [0x006B55DF+1005023]
    Ordinal0 [0x006B57CB+1005515]
    Ordinal0 [0x006E7632+1209906]
    Ordinal0 [0x006D1AD4+1120980]
    Ordinal0 [0x006E59E2+1202658]
    Ordinal0 [0x006D18A6+1120422]
    Ordinal0 [0x006AA73D+960317]
    Ordinal0 [0x006AB71F+964383]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A8E7E2+2743074]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A808D4+2685972]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00872BAA+532202]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00871990+527568]
    Ordinal0 [0x0078080C+1837068]
    Ordinal0 [0x00784CD8+1854680]
    Ordinal0 [0x00784DC5+1854917]
    Ordinal0 [0x0078ED64+1895780]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75ADFEF9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77597BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77597B8E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\driver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")


driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Images")
button.click()
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/  has no element "images" ...

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the stack trace:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Images"]"}
```

First of all, which element are you trying to select? I don't see an element called "images" on  Google. That would explain the error.

If such an element does exist and you are unable to access it, use `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '<xpath-to-element>')` ([doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)), which works better where finding elements by names fail.

Comment: Hi the code is successfully worked in other site but not working in Google.

Comment: Which other site are you referring to, and what was your code exactly?